# Free drawing to straight lines

Tags: html, canvas

I have started developing a canvas application to create rooms in 2d. I want to create a room from a free drawing like this:

http://soud.se/images/room.JPG

Example: devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example2.html (cant create more than 2 hyper links)

When the free drawing of the room is complete and mouse button is released(or when a button is pressed), I want the program automatically generates a room with straight lines like this:

http://soud.se/images/room1.JPG

I only want rooms with 90degrees corners so i wonder if there is any way to do this.

//Andreas

Comment: Why do you want to free draw the room? Why not click to start the process and then a series of clicks to draw alternative horizontal and vertical lines ending at the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/5LWES/)**

Heres one way to do it. I use 2 canvas objects, you "paint" on the top one and once you release the mouse it draws a straight line from the start point to the end point of your line. There's room for improvement but I just wanted to put one solution out there.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    drawCanvas = document.getElementById("drawCanvas"),
    drawCtx = drawCanvas.getContext("2d"),
    painting = false,
    lastX = 0,
    lastY = 0,
    startX = 0,
    startY = 0,
    lineThickness = 1;

canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;

drawCanvas.width = drawCanvas.height = 600;

drawCanvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    painting = true;
    drawCtx.fillStyle = "#000";
    lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    startX = lastX;
    startY = lastY;
};

drawCanvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    painting = false;
    var x2 = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y2 = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();

    drawCtx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
}

drawCanvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (painting) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        // find all points between        
        var x1 = mouseX,
            x2 = lastX,
            y1 = mouseY,
            y2 = lastY;


        var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
        if (steep){
            var x = x1;
            x1 = y1;
            y1 = x;

            var y = y2;
            y2 = x2;
            x2 = y;
        }
        if (x1 > x2) {
            var x = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x;

            var y = y1;
            y1 = y2;
            y2 = y;
        }

        var dx = x2 - x1,
            dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
            error = 0,
            de = dy / dx,
            yStep = -1,
            y = y1;

        if (y1 < y2) {
            yStep = 1;
        }


        for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
            if (steep) {
                drawCtx.fillRect(y, x, lineThickness , lineThickness );
            } else {
                drawCtx.fillRect(x, y, lineThickness , lineThickness );
            }

            error += de;
            if (error >= 0.5) {
                y += yStep;
                error -= 1.0;
            }
        }



        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;

    }
}
​
```